# JHipster microservices entities

Tags: jhipster, microservices

I read the [BFF pattern](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/bff-soundcloud) and I have a doubt, if one microservice is only for iOS and other microservice is only for Android, how must be created the entities if that two services use the same database and the same tables?

I'm trying to use the JDL-Studio and importing the model with import-idl command but I don't know if the command must run in every micro service's workspace

Edit:

For more context, I want to build a full stack application that could have a lot of concurrency from a web page, iOS and Android applications with REST calls and I don't know if correct to repeat the entities in every microservices (to have separated the API for every plataform) or add just one microservices as database layer.

Edit 2:
I found this [blog](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/06/20/develop-microservices-with-jhipster) talking about create jhipster applications with microservices and this guy show how the gateway have they own entities and the microservices have they own too..

now, I have more clear the real base of the microservices architecture but what if I want a microservice with the all entities and the gateway with only the UI entities? the blog show how could be this but with just one entity and I have a full model.jhl with the all entities

Comment: Each service has its own database, that's the foundation rule of microservices architecture: share nothing. Please clarify your question and give context.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use import-idl for any of them apart from the original master back-end API application.  You don't want a full back-end stack for each BFF, otherwise you'll have to maintain several applications much of what do the same thing and plus you'll need to synchronize your data between these data sources into some sort of "master". If you repoint everything to a single database and share all entities between BFF components, then it doesn't fit the microservice model.

The BFF pattern is supposed to be a thin facade in front of an existing service API that filters and perhaps calls multiple service APIs when necessary to aggregate stuff to suit each client type. I see this pattern more of a convenience band-aid when you have no control over the existing API, or a (temporary) step in incremental service decomposition. Ideally microservices should not have such synchronous dependencies, and I'm not a huge fan of horizontal decomposition.

In my opinion there are better ways of implementing "BFF" functionality if developing from scratch without the complicated architecture and added latency of adding yet another layer of indirection.  Microservice architecture is often compared to UNIX commands.  The same UNIX command is capable of supplying more detailed information when desired to suit different needs.  Compare the output of `ls` with `ls -l` for example.  Such a strategy can be applied to single microservice endpoints as well.

Comment: now I have clearer the microservices concept but now I want to have a JHipster microservice as database layer and the gateway with the UI entities only... with the jhipster entity command the wizard ask if the entity come from a microservice but, I don't know how do this with the all model in my model.jdl file and the jhipster-import-jdl command